# How can I find out the exact query that gets executed with LINQ to SQL in DbLinq and SQLite?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sqlite, dblinq

I'm using DbLinq with SQLite for a small project of mine. Is there any way to look at the actual SQL queries that get executed behind the scenes?

I remember a monitoring program for SQL Server from my internship but SQLite is a quite different beast, I fear.

Comment: Is the SQL written out to `context.Log` insufficient?

Comment: Joey: Your database context should have a `Log` property of type `TextWriter`. If you assign `context.Log = Console.Out;` you should get the SQL written out to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database context should have a `Log` property of type `TextWriter`. If you assign `context.Log = Console.Out;` for example, you should get the SQL written out to the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate you may find the Tier Interaction Profiler helpful.  There was a good blog post recently on [Skinner's Blog over on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/09/03/the-tier-interaction-profiler-tip.aspx)
that included viewing the generated SQL code

Comment: Hm, might take a few days to get my hands on Ultimate. Will that profiler work with databases other than SQL Server?

Comment: From his follow up post I believe that the TIP is actually hooked in to ADO.NET so provided that you're accessing your DB through a compatible driver then it should hook properly.  Caveat is that it needs to be web application/site or the TIP won't work as per that blog post but his follow up one shows a work around. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/09/06/tip-support-for-any-ado-net-app.aspx